# Spring pagination with oracle databse

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 tables

content

| Id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |

content_prop

| Id | name | value | content_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Value1 | 1 |
| 2 | B | Value2 | 2 |

Realationship betweet them is one to many.

I want to retrive 10 content and i use JpaSpecificationExecutor to handle pagination and complex filter.

Oracle generate next sql to retrieve entities:

select
c1_0.id
from content c1_0
left join content_prop c2_0 on c1_0.id=c2_0.content_id
where c2_0.value in('value1', 'valu2') offset 0 rows fetch first 10 rows only;

but join generate additional rows and i see less than 10 entities

How i can handle that situation?

I expect 10 entities